# Changing View of Attribute Table

Tags: qgis, attribute-table

I have someone how changed the view that the Attributes are displayed when right clicking on a layer > "Open Attribute Table".

I don't see the individual cells but instead see a view that appears to be the structure of the table. How to I change it back?

[image]

Answer (score 28, accepted):

You need to click on the **Switch to table view** button:

[image]

Comment: Been trying to figure this out for 12 months :)

Comment: yipes, that's really hidden in the corner there

Comment: Was stuck for 2 hours on this!!